# Count certain occurrences with multiple conditions: groupby(), count or len

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, count

I have the following dataframe tran:

```
SourceLoc DestLoc        SourceEq  DestEq   TypeT        
Loc1         Loc1           Eq1      Eq2    Make
Loc1         Loc2           Eq1      Eq1    Transfer
Loc1         Loc3           Eq2      Eq2    Transfer
Vend         Loc2           Eq1      Eq1    Buy
Loc2         Loc3           Eq1      Eq2    MakeTransfer
Loc2         Loc3           Eq2      Eq2    Transfer
```

I want to count the number of rows with the following conditions:

1. TypeT is ONLY Transfer OR MakeTransfer
2. It must be counted by:
   SourceLoc AND DestLoc (for all SourceEq AND DestEq combinations)

My code (the results are stored in the new column "count"):

```
tran=tran.groupby(['SourceLoc','DestLoc']).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'count'})
```

I do not know how to incorporate the condition tran['TypeT'].isin(['Transfer', 'MakeTransfer'])

It must be done BEFORE the count() function is used. Ideally, I  want a new dataframe with the column "count".

The result must be:

```
SourceLoc     DestLoc  count
Loc1          Loc2       1
Loc1          Loc3       1
Loc2          Loc3       2
```

Appreciate your help very much!!

Answer (score 3):

You can filter your dataframe with [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) then use [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html) to get the expected result:

```
>>> (df[df['TypeT'].isin(['Transfer', 'MakeTransfer'])]
       .value_counts(['SourceLoc', 'DestLoc'], sort=False).reset_index())
  SourceLoc DestLoc  count
0      Loc1    Loc2      1
1      Loc1    Loc3      1
2      Loc2    Loc3      2
```

As `value_counts` doesn't count `Nan`, you can also use [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) instead of indexing to filter your dataframe:

```
>>> (df.where(df['TypeT'].isin(['Transfer', 'MakeTransfer']))
       .value_counts(['SourceLoc', 'DestLoc'], sort=False).reset_index())
  SourceLoc DestLoc  count
0      Loc1    Loc2      1
1      Loc1    Loc3      1
2      Loc2    Loc3      2
```

If you want to use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), you can use `as_index=False` as parameter to avoid chaining `reset_index`:

```
>>> (df[df['TypeT'].isin(['Transfer', 'MakeTransfer'])]
       .groupby(['SourceLoc', 'DestLoc'], as_index=False).size())
  SourceLoc DestLoc  size
0      Loc1    Loc2     1
1      Loc1    Loc3     1
2      Loc2    Loc3     2
```

Comment: how do I add "count" column? I do not see it in the code

Comment: `value_counts` create a `Series` named `count` so when you reset the index of the `Series`, the column will be named `count`.

Comment: Hmmm,  actually it did not create a column 'count' in my case. But I got the idea. Thanks!

Comment: By default, `value_counts` returns a `Series`. If your version of Pandas is older, maybe you should rename the `Series` before resetting the index: `df[...].value_counts(...).rename('count').reset_index()`.

Answer (score 1):

I think ou can filter your DataFrame based on the TypeT column before performing the groupby operation.

```
> # Filter the DataFrame tran = tran[tran['TypeT'].isin(['Transfer', 'MakeTransfer'])]
> 
> # Perform the groupby operation tran = tran.groupby(['SourceLoc', 'DestLoc']).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'count'})
```

In this updated code, the tran[tran['TypeT'].isin(['Transfer', 'MakeTransfer'])] line filters the DataFrame to only include rows where the TypeT column is either ‘Transfer’ or ‘MakeTransfer’. The filtered DataFrame is then used in the groupby operation.

Let me know..

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes Pandas's `query` is more efficient (versatile). Also, I used `count` instead of `size` because if there's `NaN`, then `size` will include it in count calculation, but `count` will ignore it.

```
df1 = df.query("TypeT.isin(['Transfer', 'MakeTransfer'])").groupby(['SourceLoc','DestLoc'], as_index = False)['TypeT'].count()
```

You can rename `TypeT` to `count` column.

```
SourceLoc DestLoc  TypeT
0      Loc1    Loc2      1
1      Loc1    Loc3      1
2      Loc2    Loc3      2
```

Comment: For some reason count() threw an error. Possibly because before becoming a data frame this data is a Series. But. great point about NaN. In my case Nan must be ignored.

Comment: If you have a series, convert it into df before running the syntax.